# How to monitor performance information in cloud computing

Tags: cloud, monitor

I want to monitor performance information in cloud computing, such as CPU utilization, memory utilization. It's easy to get performance information in a single machine, but how to aggregate these information to provide a overall view for users and support different granularity query for performance information of machines. Is there a software which can perfectly solve this problem? Or how can I to design a distributed monitoring system  to solve it? Your answers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the following:

1. [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)
3. [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/)
4. [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

Nagios provides data and alarm aggregation too.

Comment: Thanks. I have studied Ganglia which usually is used in cluster or grid computing monitoring. Can it work well in cloud computing which we should also get the information of virtual machines?

Comment: @joey: Yes, ganglia will work for virtual machines. The agent needs to be installed on it too. It will make no difference to it if it is working on virtualized environment or real one. Cheers.